# Slicing Tensorflow Tensor with Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use the "advanced", numpy-style slicing that was added in this [PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4638), however I am running into the [same issue as the user here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4638#issuecomment-280628159):

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_15' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [3,2], [1,2], [1,2], [1].
```

Namely I would like to do the equivalent of this numpy operation (works in numpy):

```
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]) 
id_rows = np.array([0,2])
A[id_rows]
```

however this does not work in TF for the error above:

```
A = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
id_rows = tf.constant([0,2])
A[id_rows]
```

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for something like this:

```
A = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
id_rows = tf.constant([[0],[2]]) #Notice the brackets
out = tf.gather_nd(A,id_rows)
```

Comment: Okay, that worked, but is there no way to accomplish this using "slicing" (ie  `__getitem__` uses `gather_nd`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the tensor as below.

```
A = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
id_rows = tf.constant(np.array([0, 2]).reshape(-1, 1))
out = tf.gather_nd(A,id_rows)
with tf.Session() as session: 
    print(session.run(out))
```